# flat rate or free shipping

Tags: checkout, magento-1.9, shipping-methods

Hello everybody,

I need to for my webshop to have free shipping when you buy 3 or more products. When you buy less then 3 product it will cost you €6,75. I have made the free shipping and flat rate through admin>system>configuration but now it show free shipping and flat rate. Costumers can choose which one they want. I have set miminum amount of products to 3 by free shipping but that doesn't work. When i put 1 product in my cart and go to Shipping Method i still see both. Does anybody knows how to fix this? Tnx

Tnx guys for helping me with this problem. It's working now. Instead of working with products i did it with price.I took the amount between the prices of 2 and 3 products

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The minimum amount for free shipping method in system configuration is the product price amount, not product quantity. You can achieve this using shopping cart price rules. Create a new rule, and under the conditions tab select Total Items Quantity  equals or greater than  3, and under the actions tab, select Free Shipping for Shipment with matching items.
This way, you can add multiple items with different quantity (ex. 3 items with qty. 1), and the final quantity in the cart will count (in this case 3).
This method has been tested in magento 1.8.1
[image]
[image]

Comment: I did that but it didn't work. i still see both flat rate and free shipping

Comment: did you remove the initial settings for free shipping?

Comment: I only have free shipping enabled yes the rest is empty in de configuration

Comment: try disabling the free shipping method

Comment: tried that but it didnt work

Comment: I've edited the answer. please try again, and don't forget to also select the customer groups which you want the rule to apply to

Comment: Everything is the same as the photos above, but it still doesn't work. I still get flat rate and free shipping . I have free shipping enabled in configuration. Is that good orc do i need to put it on disabled?

Comment: disable the free shipping from system configuration

Comment: Still doesn't work i only see the flat rate now.

Comment: are you using the default magento checkout, or a custom onestepcheckout module?

Comment: I am using the magento default checkout

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom shipping method for this.
[See here a tutorial on how to do it.](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/shipping/create-shipping-method-module).

The only thing you need to change is the `collectRates` method.
Make it look like this:

```
public function collectRates(Mage_Shipping_Model_Rate_Request $request)
  {
    // skip if not enabled
    if (!Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/active')) {
        return false;
    }
     $result = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result');
     // create new instance of method rate
     $method = Mage::getModel('shipping/rate_result_method');
      // record carrier information
      $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
      $method->setCarrierTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/title'));

      // record method information
      $method->setMethod($this->_code);
      $method->setMethodTitle(Mage::getStoreConfig('carriers/'.$this->_code.'/title'));

      //calculate the price:
      $itemsCount = 0;
      foreach ($request->getAllItems() as $item){
           //get only real products
           if (!$item->getParentItemId()) {
               $itemsCount++;
           }
      }
      if ($itemsCount >= 3) {
          $price = 0;
      }
      else {
          $price = 6.75; //or you can use a config value
      }


      $method->setPrice($price);
      $result->append($method);
    }

    return $result;
  }
```